# Enumerator value evaluates to 2147483648, which cannot be narrowed to type 'int'

Tags: c++, c++11

I created an enum like this:

```
enum class CATEGORIES{
       C01 = 0x00000001,
       C02 = 0x00000002,
       C03  = 0x00000004,
       ...
       C26 = 0x02000000,
       C27 = 0x04000000,
       C28 = 0x08000000,
       C29 = 0x10000000,
       C30 = 0x20000000,
       C31 = 0x40000000,
       C32 = 0x80000000, //Error at this line
    }
```

> Enumerator value evaluates to 2147483648, which cannot be narrowed to
> type 'int'

How should I resolve it? I just wanted a convenient way of representing the categories, and enum class seemed to make sense for namespacing..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forcing enum to be of unsigned long type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084542/forcing-enum-to-be-of-unsigned-long-type)

Answer (score 4):

`0x80000000` is `2147483648` in base 10, and an `int` (32 bit on most compilers) cannot contain `2147483648`

You should do this:

```
enum class CATEGORIES : unsigned long{
       C01 = 0x00000001,
       C02 = 0x00000002,
       C03 = 0x00000004,
       ...
       C26 = 0x02000000,
       C27 = 0x04000000,
       C28 = 0x08000000,
       C29 = 0x10000000,
       C30 = 0x20000000,
       C31 = 0x40000000,
       C32 = 0x80000000,
}; // also you seem to miss this semicolon
```

Comment: Minor point: "an `int` cannot contain `2147483648`" isn't quite right. A **32-bit** int cannot contain `2147483648`. Depending on the compiler, it's possible for `int` to be larger than that (not to mention smaller, as well). +1.

Answer (score 3):

Someone suggested the following and then deleted their comment, but it seemed to work, making the underlying type unsigned int:

```
enum class CATEGORIES : uint32_t{
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without specifying explicitly the underlying type of `CATEGORIES` is `int`, and `0x80000000` (`2147483648`) is outside of the range of `int` on your platform.

You can specify a larger type (e.g. `long`; depending on your needs) as the underlying type explicitly.

```
enum class CATEGORIES : long {
   C01 = 0x00000001,
   C02 = 0x00000002,
   C03  = 0x00000004,
   ...
   C26 = 0x02000000,
   C27 = 0x04000000,
   C28 = 0x08000000,
   C29 = 0x10000000,
   C30 = 0x20000000,
   C31 = 0x40000000,
   C32 = 0x80000000,
};
```